# How do you rotate a cell in Numbers (3.2)?

Tags: numbers

I want to rotate the header row by 45 degrees to look like this (from Excel).

[image]

How do you do this in Numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This is currently not possible within cells.**

As a workaround, you can change the angle of the text labels for the X axis on a chart and use this as the header for your table.

[image]

Alternatively, you can create text boxes and rotate these.

You can provide feedback to Apple regarding this on the following page:

- https://www.apple.com/feedback/numbers.html

Comment: Thanks for including that link for feedback—it's absolutely ridiculous that an otherwise impressive program can't do this very very basic thing.  (It has other failings though, and this is the last straw for me, but I contributed my feedback anyway, in hopes that it would help someone.)

Comment: A subtlety regarding use of vertical text in a text box is that iCloud Numbers will apparently only open a Numbers file containing vertical text in text boxes as a Read-Only image. :-( (For that reason, I can't use vertical text, unfortunately.) "Numbers for iCloud can open a read-only image of a spreadsheet with vertical text." [Numbers User Guide for Mac: Use vertical text in Numbers on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/numbers/use-vertical-text-tan8df